# Horizontal scroll with one row of cards in Adaptive Cards Power BI

Tags: powerbi, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to integrate Adaptive cards into Power BI. But it always lets me scroll vertically. Would it be possible to have just one row of cards scrolling horizontally without a limit?

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cnOm.png)